# Symfony 2 : Error on EntityManager::flush with message "ArrayCollection::__construct() must be an array, object given"

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to update position of entity collection (subentities) for a specific entity (master entity). Everything work until method execute flush instruction to push updates to database.

Error Message is :

```
Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection::__construct() must be an array, object given, called in \vendor\doctrine\lib\Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork.php on line 426 and defined in \vendor\doctrine-common\lib\Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection.php line 46
```

Controller method is :

```
public function layoutAction($id, $entity, $subentity)
{
    //-- Get Repository for master entity class
    $object  = $this->getRepository($entity)->find($id);
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();     

    //-- Get form datas
    $datas = $this->get('request')->get('items', array());

    //-- Update position for each msater entity childs of given subentity
    $method = "get" . ucfirst($subentity) . "s";        
    foreach($object->$method() as $item){
        $item->setPosition(array_search($item->getId(), $datas));
        $em->persist($item);            
    }

    //-- Push updates
    $em->flush();

    //-- Notification + Redirection
    ...
}
```

Master entity have one-to-many relationship with subentity and subentity have one-to-one relationship with master entity. Sample declaration below :

Master entity :

```
<one-to-many field="subentities" target-entity="Subentity" mapped-by="masterentity" />
```

Subentity :

```
<one-to-one field="masterentity" target-entity="MasterEntity" inversed-by="subentities">
    <join-column name="idMaster" referenced-column-name="idMaster" />
</one-to-one>
```

I don't understand why this error is triggered but I believe that it comes from relationship.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your map is confusing. If you defined **one** Masterentity has **many** subentities, then for `Subentity::masterentity` you should set reverse relationship: **many-to-one** instead of  one-to-one.

Comment: It was indeed one-to-one relationship that cause this error. When I replace one-to-one by many-to-one and my error disappeared and update succeed. Thanks Meze !